# pandas sample based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use pandas [sample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) function but with a criteria without grouping or filtering data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=(10000, 2)),columns=['a', 'b'])

print(df.sample(n=100))
```

This will sample 100 rows, but what if i want to sample 50 rows containing 0 to 50 rows containing 1 in `df['a']`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `==` operator to make a list* of boolean values.  And when said list is put into the getter (`[]`) it will filter the values.  If you want to, you can use `n=50` to create a sample size of 50 rows.

## New code

```
df[df['a']==1].sample(n=50)
```

## Full code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=(10000, 2)),columns=['a', 'b'])

print(df[df['a']==1].sample(n=50))
```

*List isn't literally a list in this context, but it is a great word for explaining how it works. It's a technically a DataFrame that maps rows to a true/false value.

## More obscure DataFrame sampling

If you want to sample all 50 where a is 1 or 0:

```
print(df[(df['a']==1) | (df['a']==0)].sample(n=50))
```

And if you want to sample 50 of each:

```
df1 = df[df['a']==1].sample(n=50)
df0 = df[df['a']==0].sample(n=50)
print(pd.concat([df1,df0]))
```

Comment: Sure. But what if you need to sample 50 each from `df['a'] == 1` and `df['a'] == 0` without some weird if statements and splitting data etc

Comment: @destinychoice Updated my answer.

Comment: I see. But your latter approach would end up having two dataframes á 50 each where it should be one df holding 100 values?

Comment: @destinychoice Updated.  If I did help, if you could mark as solution / upvote, it'd help a lot.

Comment: @Neil how can I add multiple criteria? for example if I wanted to sample based on col a=1, b=5, Z="Michael"...etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will support as many values as you like (e.g. 0,1,2,3):

```py
selected_rows = df.groupby('a', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=50))
```