# Selecting different no. of random rows from pandas dataframe based on counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have a data frame with 10000 rows,2 columns(text and category) and 3 categories (pos,neg and neutral). I want to randomly select 5000 rows of positive class and 2500 rows each for negative class and neutral class. I am able to do 5000 rows of each class. But I am wondering how to select different no. of rows for different classes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `pd.concat` like this: `pd.concat([pos_class, neg_class, neu_class])`

Comment: Please see the following link: [pandas sample based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432224/pandas-sample-based-on-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample` to do so.

```
import random
# Return a list of indices
pos_idx = random.sample(list(df.query('category=="pos"').index),5000)
neg_idx = random.sample(list(df.query('category=="neg"').index),2500)
neu_idx = random.sample(list(df.query('category=="neu"').index),2500)

# Use indices to select data
df_sample = df.loc[pos_idx + neg_idx + neu_idx]
```